# Does ASP.NET limit memory usage of single-objects? 256MB byte array throwing OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net, memory

I have an ASP.NET application.

The following throws a System.OutOfMemoryException:

```
byte[] test = new byte[268435456];
```

At the time I call this, the current memory usage is 158MB, per

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long value = proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

Locally, I'm running 32 bit Windows 7, and in production we are Windows Server 2008R2, 64 bit.   Both boxes have 4GB memory.  While my box is at about 5GB per Windows Task Manager, the production box is <3GB.  Either way, both boxes have memory availble (mine on the pagefile).  Is there more than 256MB overhead in creating a byte array of 256MB (268435456 bytes) in length?  Is there an inherit limitation in ASP.NET?

EDIT: The "Private Memory Limit" on the application pool on the 2008R2 box is set to 0 (no limit)

Comment: Do you have set on the pools to avoid restart the pool in case of big memory use ?

Comment: @Aristos both Private Memory Limit and Virtual Memory Limit are set to 0 (no recycle). Also, I see this behavior locally with IIS Express (not sure how to change settings there)

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory exceptions occur because .net cannot allocate enough contiguous memory from the large heap. Even though your system has 4gb of memory, user space is a max of 2gb.

This works fine on my windows 7 64bit version of windows with 4gb of memory.